# Date arithmetic - get all mondays

Tags: codenameone

How would I do Date arithmetic in Codename One?
For example - if one needs to get all mondays in a time interval - what is the best way to do that in Codename One?

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I looked into SimpleDateFormat and found `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault())` which can be used to do the date arithmetics.